# How to join multiple separate faces into one mesh

Tags: modeling, import

I imported a model into Blender and all faces are separate. Nothing is connected together except the three vertices of each triangle. Is there any way to join all of the triangular faces at once in a logical manner? This is the model with one face separate for demonstration purposes.

[image]

Comment: Select all, ctrl-V -> remove doubles. On the left there is a panel where you can adjust threshold for merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice while in edit mode to select all faces (will be outlined in orange, then key <kbd>W</kbd> and click on *Remove Doubles* from the menu that appears.

[image]